# OpenGL Texturing Isn't working: displaying just white

Tags: opengl, textures

Basically, see the title: for whatever reason, I load a texture into OpenGL, bind it, draw a quad with texture coordinates specified, and the quad remains totally white regardless of what the texture is.

I have made sure that GL_TEXTURE_2D is enabled. I have verified (using glGetTexImage) that the Texture has the correct data in it (or, if not the correct data, data that should be visible, as the pixels have different values).

My glTexture2D function is called as follows:

`glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, pixelFormat, this->width, this->height, 0, pixelFormat, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &(pixelData[0]));`

This is where pixel format is either GL_RGBA or GL_RGB (according to pixel depth), and pixelData is the array of pixels. I verified that pixelFormat and pixelData and width and height have within them the correct values. Note that pixelData is a std::vector.

I bind the texture as such:

`glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + this->multiTexNumber);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->texID);`

For the purposes of my testing, this->multiTexNumber = 0;

Have I done something wrong here? Is the problem elsewhere?

EDIT: via **very** thorough checking, I have ensured that OpenGL doesn't throw any errors. The problem persists.

Comment: `pixelFormat` These are ***not the same thing!*** There is a big difference between the [internal image format](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format) and the [pixel transfer format](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer). I really wish the OpenGL ARB would have just made two separate sets of enums so people wouldn't be confused.

Comment: I tried screwing around with changing their values, which did nothing.

Comment: That wasn't a suggestion to fix your problem; that was telling you how OpenGL works. That's why it was a comment instead of an answer. Though I would suggest, if you want an actual answer, you need to get a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I'm not sure I can pull that off simply enough. Th code contains stuff that reads image files, pushes things into vertex buffers, etc. It took me a long time to verify that each component was filled with the proper data.

Comment: If we assume your code is working (since you haven't provided it, we can't say), then the only thing to suggest is an OpenGL bug, that texturing on your graphics card is broken. Since that's unlikely, the bug must be in your code. And since we can't see your code, because it's too big to provide and you can't pull together a small example that has the problem... what exactly do you expect us to do to help you? You have a code bug. In order for us to help you debug it, we would need to see your code.

Comment: I've given you the code that could be problematic. The rest of it works, and I've verified that myself: the vertex buffer drawing and texture loading etc. all work, I checked the contents of the buffers myself. It's just these two functions. Is something wrong with them?

Comment: The safest place for a bug to hide is in code that you are utterly convinced is correct.

Comment: Of course, that's why I so thoroughly tested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not providing a full mip chain for the texture, ensure that mipmapping is disabled (set a filter mode that doesn't use mipmaps).  IIRC, OpenGL may disable texturing if you try to use mipmapping on a texture that doesn't have mips.